# Shared WAR and logback logging separation

Tags: java, logging, tomcat7

I'm trying to achieve a separation of logging for web applications using logback ( http://logback.qos.ch ) under Tomcat 7. I've read all the tutorials on their websiste, ie.:

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html

It relies on providing JNDI entries in each web application web.xml and using them in logback configuration. It's plain and simple. The problem is tough, I have only one WAR which is being deployed under several contexts via separate context configuration (under TOMCAT_HOME\conf\Catalina\localhost):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="c:\applications\app" path="/Test1" reloadable="true">
</Context>
```

With this approach, I'm not able to modify web.xml file to provide a distinct app name. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a ServletContextListener :

```
public class YourContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
...
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
...
}
```

And in the contextInitialized method update the logback context name JNDI value of the application with information from servlet context path.